# Summation of terms involving contractions with 3 Levi Civita tensors

Tags: list-manipulation, symbolic, summation, tensors

I am trying to evaluate this expression:

$\epsilon^{abcdef}X^R_a X^S_b X^T_c X^U_d X^V_e X^W_f \epsilon_{RST} \epsilon_{UVW}$

where:

$X = \frac{a^2 +b^2-1}{2a} \mathbb 1_6$

and I wrote this code to evaluate it with the range of parameters $a,b,c,d,e,f$ running from 1 to 6, while $R,S,T, U,V,W$ running from 1 to 3.

```
Sum[
 Signature[{a, b, c, d, e, f}] X[[R, a]] X[[S, b]] X[[T, c]] X[[U, 
    d]] X[[V, e]] X[[W, f]] Signature[{R, S, T}] Signature[{U, V, W}]
 , {a, 1, 6}
 , {b, 1, 6}
 , {c, 1, 6}
 , {d, 1, 6}
 , {e, 1, 6}
 , {f, 1, 6}
 , {R, 1, 3}
 , {S, 1, 3}
 , {T, 1, 3}
 , {U, 1, 3}
 , {V, 1, 3}
 , {W, 1, 3}
 ]
```

but it seems that *Mathematica* takes forever to evaluate this. I don't know of any other way to make it faster and would appreciate it very much if anyone could help me. Thanks !

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.
Why not choosing a meaningful name?

Comment: Probably you could share the code you used to define `X[[R, a]]` ?

Comment: X is an $6\times 6$ diagonal matrix - the product of the $6\times 6$ identity matrix times a factor $(a^2+b^2-1)/2a$, so X[[R,a]] is just an element of this $6\times 6$ matrix. For example: X[[1,1]] = $(a^2+b^2-1)/2a$ while X[[1,0]] = 0. $R$ and $a$ are just dummy indices running from 1 to 3 and 1 to 6, respectively.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the problem into simpler parts. You can define the tensor $A_{abc} = X_a^R X_b^SX_c^T\epsilon_{RST}$,

```
X = (a^2 + b^2 - 1)/(2 a) IdentityMatrix[6];
lc3 = LeviCivitaTensor[3] // Normal;
lc6 = LeviCivitaTensor[6] // Normal;

A = 
  Table[Sum[
    X[[R, a]] X[[S, b]] X[[T, c]] lc3[[R, S, T]], {R, 1, 3}, {S, 1, 
     3}, {T, 1, 3}], {a, 1, 6}, 
       {b, 1, 6}, {c, 1, 6}]//Simplify
```

Then the expression that you want to compute is simply $\epsilon^{abcdef}A_{abc}A_{def}$. From this we can already say that the result will vanish, because $A_{abc}A_{def}$ is symmetric under the interchange of $(a,b,c)\leftrightarrow (d,e,f)$ and $\epsilon^{abcdef}$ is antisymmetric.

We can check this easily

```
Sum[lc6[[a, b, c, d, e, f]] A[[a, b, c]] A[[d, e, f]], {a, 1, 6}, {b, 
  1, 6}, {c, 1, 6}, {d, 1, 6}, {e, 1, 6}, {f, 1, 6}]//Simplify
```

Sadly, this doesn't explain why it is not working for you, but gives you a way to perform the computation.

Comment: Note that doing the full sum involves $3^6 \cdot 6^6 = 34,012,224$ terms, whereas defining $A_{abc}$ involves a sum over $6^3 \cdot 3^3 = 5832$ terms, and calculating the final sum then involves $6^6 = 46,656$ terms.  So it's not surprising that Mathematica likes your method better.

Comment: Thank you very much ! That works brilliantly !

Comment: ...  As evidence of my previous comment, I tried running the OP's code but with `Signature` replaced by `lc3` or `lc6` respectively.  It returned `0` about 45 minutes later.